# Barplot with both stacked and grouped options, without face grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to make a stacked and grouped barplot using the following datasets:

```
dfplot  <- data.frame(organisms=c("M.musculus","D.melanogaster" ,"H.sapiens","O.sativa","S.pombe","C.familiaris",
           "G.gallus","P.falciparum","A.thaliana","C.elegans","D.rerio","B.taurus","S.cerevisiae","R.norvegicus","C.intestinalis","B.subtilis","E.coli"),                  
                      KEGGv2=c(20,7,21,126,106,62,26,80,5,5,13,306,8,35,32,104,107), 
                      KEGGv1=c(286,124,289,0,0,244,135,0,121,124,148,0,101,271,87,0,0),
                      Reactome=c(358,146,596,115,54,306,370,23,155,112,365,341,52,364,0,0,0))

# Melt the dataframe
melted <- melt(dfplot, "organisms")

# Reformat the data labels
melted$cat <- ''
melted[melted$variable == 'Reactome',]$cat <- "Reactome"
melted[melted$variable != 'Reactome',]$cat <- "KEGG"


ggplot(melted, aes(x=cat, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') +
  facet_grid(~ organisms)+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("deepskyblue4", "lightblue1", "olivedrab2")) +
  labs(y = "Number of Pathways") +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        legend.title=element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

And my output is the following one:

[image]

I used a facet_grid per organism because I wanted to have a mix between `stack` (for both KEGGv1 and KEGGv2) and then group it with the other group `Reactome`. However, when doing the melting, the x-axis will have two labels per facet_grid (KEGG and Reactome, which is the variable obtained from the melting [cat]). I did not want that label so I remove them.

What I am trying to do is to have the organism name per each of the groupings, so each of the 17 grouping bars will have the name of the corresponding organism**. Therefore, I am missing that, I have tried several ways but I cannot find the proper way of doing it.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do two things to make this work:

1. Rotate the labels of the facet so that they plot at 90 degrees
2. Plot the facet labels beneath the graph using the `switch = 'x'` argument within `facet_grid`.

Here is the complete example:

```
  ggplot(melted, aes(x=cat, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') +
    facet_grid(~organisms, switch = 'x')+ 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("deepskyblue4", "lightblue1", "olivedrab2")) +
    labs(y = "Number of Pathways") +
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
          axis.text.x=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
          legend.title=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "black"),
          strip.text = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

I left the default shaded background, but you can easily style as you prefer.

### Aproach Two

You might want to consider rotating the plot. This requires you to flip the coordinates of the plot using `coord_flip` **before** the facet is called. As we are faceting in the other direction we change the facet argument to `facet_grid(organisms~.)`. All other arguments which refer to x or y are swapped over:

```
  ggplot(melted, aes(x=cat, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') +
    coord_flip() +
    facet_grid(organisms~., switch = 'y')  +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("deepskyblue4", "lightblue1", "olivedrab2")) +
    labs(y = "Number of Pathways") +
    theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
          axis.text.y=element_blank(),
          axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
          legend.title=element_blank(),
          panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
          panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
          panel.background = element_blank(),
          axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black"),
          strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 180))
```

[image]

Comment: Really, really nice! Thanks! I added also "strip.background = element_blank()" to remove the rectangles background.

Comment: Glad you like it! If you don't want the box, you might want to use the argument  `hjust = 1` in the `strip.text.y = element_text(angle = 180, hjust = 1)` to force the text to be right aligned

Comment: I will use it, its even better now! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you can set the organism labels to be below the bars, rather than above.  This is established by setting the **switch** argument of the **facet_grid** function to "**x**" (see code below).  Secondly, you should then remove **axis.title.x=element_blank()** argument within your theme function call.  The updated code is below. Hope this helps!

```
ggplot(melted, aes(x = cat, y = value, fill =variable)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'stack') +facet_grid(~organisms, switch="x")+ 
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("deepskyblue4","lightblue1","olivedrab2"))+
    ylab("Number of pathways")+
    theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
    theme(strip.background = element_blank())+theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```